# How do I find an inverse for this injective multivariate function?

Tags: inverse

I have come up with an injective multivariate function that puts out a unique value for every configuration of four positive natural numbers provided that
$\omega\ge\psi\ge\chi\ge\theta\ge1$

$f(\omega,\psi,\chi,\theta)= \frac{\omega^4+2\omega^3-\omega^2-2\omega}{24}+\frac{\psi^3-\psi}{6}+\frac{\chi^2-\chi}{2}+\theta$

f(4,2,2,1) = 18

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ is really injective with your restriction $\omega\ge\psi\ge\chi\ge\theta$ then it means that $f(\omega+1,1,1,1)>f(\omega,\omega,\omega,\omega)$, else we have a contradiction. So it's simple to find the value of $\omega$, by finding the largest integer $\omega$ so $f(\omega,1,1,1)$ doesn't exceed the value of the function to be inverted.

You can then find the next values in chain ($\psi$,$\chi$,$\theta$), using a similar technique.

Comment: Sorry, I should've mentioned that the four numbers can only be natural numbers, we can't put 0 in any of them so the function is truly injective with that restriction.

Comment: @leaven this doesn't change the argument. I changed the answer anyway for clarity.

Comment: Thanks. I understand it.